# how to take input from .sh file in java

Tags: java, bash, unix

My task is to implement Distance Vector Multicast Routing Protocol (DVMRP) using files (No sockets or threads). I will have three java programs

1. Host.java
2. Router.java
3. Controller.java

The procedure for testing is:

1. Run the test1.sh script file on a new terminal window

test1.sh looks like:

```
rm -f lan?  hout?  hin?
rm -f rout?
router 0 0 1 &
router 1 1 2 &
router 2 2 3 &
router 3 3 0 &
controller host router 0 1 2 3 lan 0 1 2 3&
```

Here, the line containing

```
router 0 0 1 &
```

means that a process is created from the executable file "router" (basically Router.java) and runs it in the background with input 0 0 1, & is I think to say that its in bash mode.

Similarly the next line

```
router 1 1 2 &
```

means that another process is created from the executable file "router" (basically Router.java) and runs in the background with input 1 1 2.

Similarly, the line:

```
controller ...
```

means that another process is created from the executable file "controller" (basically Controller.java) and runs in the background with the corresponding input.

How to do this? Sorry for earlier confusion :)

Comment: What's the problem? You can do: `java Router 0 0 1 &`

Comment: OP wants to know how to call the sh script from Java with the appropriate arguments

Comment: By the last line in the script "controller host router 0 1 2 3 lan 0 1 2 3&", do you mean to invoke the Controller.java program with the parameters "host router 0 1 2 3 lan 0 1 2 3", or do you intend to have "router 0 1 2 3" be replaced by running this is a command? What is the output of the router command?

Comment: The last line is meant to execute the controller process (executed once only) and the input is:

`router 0...9 host 0...9 lan 0...9`

This input tells the controller process that there are

routers and their router-id which ranges from 0 to 9,


hosts and their host-id which ranges from 0 to 9,


lans and their lab-id which ranges from 0 to 9

Answer (score 4):

First you compile your java program:

```
javac Router.java
```

You should invoke java like this:

```
java Router 0 0 1 &
```

You can find a Hello World [example here](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html)

**Edit**: I am still not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, but you might try to change the above test1.sh to this:

```
rm -f lan?  hout?  hin?
rm -f rout?
java Router 0 0 1 &
java Router 1 1 2 &
java Router 2 2 3 &
java Router 3 3 0 &
java Controller host router 0 1 2 3 lan 0 1 2 3&
```

This will spawn 4 instances of Router and one instance of Controller.
This assumes that you have compiled the programs first:

```
javac Router.java Controller.java Host.java
```

Comment: I have three programs Host.java, Router.java & Controller.java (implementing DVMRP using files). So first Host.java is run from a terminal window, then Router.java from another terminal window and then Controller.java from yet another terminal window.

Then the shell script file is executed on yet another terminal.

Comment: I do not follow what you mean. .java files are compiled to binary(-ish) .class files which are invoked with "java <classname>". Can you rephrase your question to elaborate what you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: I am editing the question with details, please wait.

Comment: Question explained in detail. Please have a look.

Comment: I just updated the proposed solution. Is this what you are trying do to?

Comment: Ya that is what I thought of initially, but upon asking my TA, I came to know that the same test case test1.sh will be run for all submissions (they can be in Java, C, C++, Objective C, Python etc).

So I was looking for workarounds. I know this is completely crazy, but the professor remains adamant and adheres strictly to this :(

but its an excellent suggestion, thank you, I appreciate it :)

Comment: I see, so the test1.sh must remain unchanged. I guess a workaround would be to create binaries called router and controller that would invoke the java equivalent. Something like a batch script called "router" with the following contents: "java Router $@" - the only problem is, that even if made executable (chmod u+x router) it will not simply run by writing "router" in the prompt.

Comment: Yup, that is true, I have dropped a mail to my professor regarding modifying the test cases as you have suggested and zipping them with my project files (that way they could run the test cases with commands modified only and the data remaining entirely the same)

The TA has agreed to this proposal, need to get approval from the  professor though, tough nut now :)

Thanks for all ur help and suggestions, lets see what it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a Java program called `Router.java` that takes the parameters, and you want to run it in the background.

If my assumption is correct, then you need to do some things:

1. Compile the java program
2. Run the program in the background

To compile your program:

```
javac Router.java
```

To run your program:

```
java Router 0 0 1 &
```

---

After reading (and reading again) your question and your comments, I think your problem is that you don't know how to pass parameters to your Java program from the command line. If that is your problem, you should remember that the `main` function has an `args` parameter, which is a way to pass values to the program from the command line. The `args` variable is an array of `String` objects that you can use in your code:

```
public class Router {
    /*
     * Your methods go here
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * The 'args' variable holds the arguments entered in the command line
         */
        if(args[0].equals("a")) {
            /*
             * This is an example of how to read the arguments supplied in the command line.
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The scenario is I compile Router.java by:
`java Router.java`

Then I run it by:
`java Router`

Similarly, I run two other programs `Host.java` & `Controller.java`
on separate Terminals.

Now I need to open up another terminal and execute the shell script file namely `test1.sh` which contains:

`rm -f lan?  hout?  hin?
rm -f rout?
router 0 0 1 &
router 1 1 2 &
router 2 2 3 &
router 3 3 0 &
controller host router 0 1 2 3 lan 0 1 2 3&`


The Host, Router and Controller processes take inputs related to them from this script file execution.

Comment: @user2961121 I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are your java programs already written and you need to call them from a shell script? Or you want to call a shell script from your java programs?

Comment: I have the java programs.

Steps:
1. Run each java program from separate terminals
2. On a new terminal run the script file which provides input for all three java programs.

Comment: @user2961121 and do the programs already run individually? have you tested them? have you compiled them?

Comment: Please have a look at the detailed question.

Comment: @user2961121 My question persists: have you tested *each* program individually? You should do that before trying to write a script. If your java programs are compiled and they run properly, then you can put them all together in a script, but still, you need to call them using `java yourProgram yourInputs`

Comment: @user2961121 Ok... I've read again all your question and your comments... And I think the issue is that you don't know how to pass arguments from the command line (or your script) to the Java program. Read my updated answer.